# Django custom login form only works on local

Tags: python, django

So I extended Django's AuthenticationForm to add placeholders and custom CSS classes for the login form like so:

```
class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'validate login-input-box', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'login-input-box', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

And in my urls.py:

```
path(r'^login/?$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': CustomAuthForm}),
```

Which I thought was completely fine, given that it worked on local. I noticed today however that on the live site, neither the placeholders nor the classes showed up on the form. I did inspect element to confirm they were missing, and I tried on different browsers, as well as doing a hard reload of the page, all to no avail. Does anyone know why this would be failing only on the live site?

It's being deployed to AWS elastic beanstalk.

Comment: wierd.. did you check difference in html?

Comment: If I do inspect element I see that the HTML is indeed different; the only difference being the absence of the classes and placeholders for those two input boxes

Comment: It's really weird situation. maybe your `CustomAuthForm` didn't apply. Did you reload your server or check your code is totally on server?

Comment: Just restarted the server and still getting same result.

Comment: How about browser cache?

Comment: Doesn't work in incognito. I have no clue why this might be happening :/